# NLP: Extract shape names and shape dimensions

Tags: c#, nlp

I am an NLP beginner. I am working on a task where I have to process a text to draw shapes.

I did some research and found that tokensregex could be a good fit.

For example

Text : Could you please draw an Isosceles triangle with an altitude of 150 and a base of 100.

In here, my approach is to write tokensregex rule to extract shape name and dimensions. Once i get these two data, I will draw the extracted shape with the given dimensions.

Is my choice of using tokensregex correct?

Or is there any other way to do it smartly?

Answer (score 2):

Given the well defined boundaries of your problem, Tokensregex could be the right way to go. You might spend some time maturing it. But it should be the preferred way. But before you finalise your approach I suggest you pitch it against some [deep parsing](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) technique. Here is what you could get that you might be able to combine with some dictionary of known shapes and write extraction logic.

```
 (ROOT
  (SQ (MD Could)
    (NP (PRP you))
    (VP (VB please)
      (VP (VB draw)
        (NP (DT an) (NNP Isosceles) (NN triangle))
        (PP (IN with)
          (NP
            (NP
              (NP (DT an) (NN altitude))
              (PP (IN of)
                (NP (CD 150))))
            (CC and)
            (NP
              (NP (DT a) (NN base))
              (PP (IN of)
                (NP (CD 100))))))))
    (. .)))
```

Here, you are getting readymade chunks of altitude - 150 and base - 100. See if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right way to do what you are asking. If all your sentences are as on the example, then the rule-based approach with dependency parsing seems like a solution where rules identify attributes and values and dependency parsing identifies relations between them.

More formally, [semantic parsing](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sempre/) should help in this case